# Elastic returns unexpected result from Search using edge_ngram

Tags: elasticsearch, search, kibana

I am working out how to store my data in elasticsearch. First I tried the fuzzy function and while that worked okay I did not receive the expected results. Afterwards I tried the `ngram` and then the `edge_ngram` tokenizer. The `edge_ngram` tokenizer looked like it works like an autocomplete. Exactly what I needed. But it still gives unexpected results. I configured `min 1` and `max 5` to get all results starting with the first letter I search for. While this works I still get those results as I continue typing.

Example: I have a name field filled with documents named `The New York Times` and `The Guardian`. Now when I search for `T` both occur as expected. But the same happens when I search for `TT`, `TTT` and so on.

In that case it does not matter wether I execute the search in Kibana or from my application (which useses `MultiMatch` on all fields). Kibana even shows me the that it matched the single letter T.

So what did I miss and how can I achieve getting the results like with an autocomplete but without having too many results?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When defining your index mapping, you need to specify [`search_analyzer`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-analyzer.html) as standard. If no `search_analyzer` is defined explicitly, then by default elasticsearch considers `search_analyzer` to be the same as that of `analyzer` specified.

Adding a working example with index data, mapping, search query and search result

**Index Mapping:**

```
{
  "settings": {
    "analysis": {
      "analyzer": {
        "autocomplete": {
          "tokenizer": "autocomplete",
          "filter": [
            "lowercase"
          ]
        }
      },
      "tokenizer": {
        "autocomplete": {
          "type": "edge_ngram",
          "min_gram": 1,
          "max_gram": 5,
          "token_chars": [
            "letter"
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "name": {
        "type": "text",
        "analyzer": "autocomplete",
        "search_analyzer": "standard"      // note this
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**Index Data:**

```
{
    "name":"The Guardian"
}
{
    "name":"The New York Times"
}
```

**Search Query:**

```
{
  "query": {
    "match": {
      "name": "T"
    }
  }
}
```

**Search Result:**

```
"hits": [
      {
        "_index": "69027911",
        "_type": "_doc",
        "_id": "1",
        "_score": 0.23092544,
        "_source": {
          "name": "The New York Times"
        }
      },
      {
        "_index": "69027911",
        "_type": "_doc",
        "_id": "2",
        "_score": 0.20824991,
        "_source": {
          "name": "The Guardian"
        }
      }
    ]
```

Comment: @CrystalCase please go through the answer, and let me know if this resolves your issue ?